# Use different chapter title in TOC, in the first chapter page, and in header

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer, memoir, chapters

Say I have two titles t1 and t2 for a chapter. I want to show t1 in TOC, and t2 in the first chapter page as well as the in the header.

I use `\chapter[t1]{t2}` which works for TOC and the first chapter page. However the header shows t1 instead of t2. Is there a way to enforce t2 in the header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `memoir`, the syntax for `\chapter` and `\section` is extended:

```
\chapter[toc-title][head-title]{title}
```

If only one argument is used, the same input is used for the TOC and the header, so you want

```
\chapter[t1][t2]{t2}
```

Similarly for `\section`.

---

Perhaps you're interested in an easier interface. I define the commands `\Chapter` and `\Section`. If called like

```
\Chapter{Title}
```

then the behavior is the same as `\chapter{title}`. But you can call

```
\Chapter[toc=Title for TOC]{Title}
```

and the title for headers will be “Title”, while in the TOC you'll get what's stated. The third way of calling it is

```
\Chapter[toc=Title for TOC,head=Title for head]{Title}
```

for specifying the three elements independently. Here's a full example.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\ExplSyntaxOn
% set up the keys
\keys_define:nn { tmv/titles }
 {
  toc  .tl_set:N = \l_tmv_titles_toc_tl,
  head .tl_set:N = \l_tmv_titles_head_tl,
 }

% user level commands    
\NewDocumentCommand{\Chapter}{ O{} m }
 {
  \tmv_set_titles:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \tmv_division:VVnN \l_tmv_titles_toc_tl \l_tmv_titles_head_tl { #2 } \chapter
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Section}{ O{} m }
 {
  \tmv_set_titles:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \tmv_division:VVnN \l_tmv_titles_toc_tl \l_tmv_titles_head_tl { #2 } \section
 }

% auxiliary command for setting the keys
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tmv_set_titles:nn #1 #2
 {
  \keys_set:nn { tmv/titles }
   {
    toc = { #2 },
    head = { #2 },
    #1
   }
 }

% the command that calls either \chapter or \section    
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tmv_division:nnnN #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  #4[#1][#2]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tmv_division:nnnN { VV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\Chapter{Unique title}
\Section{Unique section title}
\kant

\Chapter[toc=Title for TOC]{Title also for head}
\Section[toc=Title for TOC]{Title also for head}
\kant

\Chapter[toc=Title for TOC 2,head=Title for head]{Title}
\Section[toc=Title for TOC 2,head=Title for head]{Title}
\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that with `part`?

Comment: @Blacksad Define `\Part` in the same way as `\Chapter`, but with `\part` replacing `\chapter` in the code.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to parse the `[` with `part`. It works with chapter and section though.

Comment: @Blacksad Sorry, but apparently `\part` doesn't allow for different texts for toc, header and title; just toc and title.

Comment: Just found this great answer! Can it be that it doesn't work with the book document class? I jsut tried copy pasting the code, and while in compiles fine, it doesn't have an effect.

Comment: @MaximMoloshenko Yes, `memoir` is essential for the double optional argument to the sectional commands.